# Connecting to DB2 works in Java, fails in .NET

Tags: db2, ado.net, db2-luw

Same machine, same server, database, username, & password. Connects fine with JDBC. With ADO.NET I get the following (using 11.1.0):

Connection string:

```
Database=SAMPLE;User ID=****;Password=****;Server=db2.windward.net
```

Inner exception is:

> Encryption - no error information available at
>   IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.EncryptString(String value)

**Update:**

1. I'm aware JDBC and ADO.NET connectors are totally distinct code. I listed that it works under JDBC to show that I can connect to the database.
2. I am using the latest 11.1 ADO.NET connector that I downloaded yesterday from IBM.
3. Another data point, the code works fine on my office system. It only fails on my home computer.

Comment: ADO.NET  and JDBC do not share code for accessing Db2.  For basic troubleshooting, have you verified that odbcad32 can connect to the Db2 database?   Which Db2-driver are you using (from Microsoft or IBM or other provider)? Which security and encryption settings are active on the Db2-server.   There is insufficient information in your question to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: If using an IBM Db2 client, verify that you are at the *latest* fixpack and ifix for the v11.1 product. These are downloadable from IBM fix central.

Comment: @mao Yes I'm using the latest driver (I updated my question). What is odbcad32 and where do I find it? TIA

Comment: Sounds like it might be a GSKit installation issue. Check out [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22014613) for hints on how to troubleshoot conflicting libraries (ignore the SSL stuff).

Comment: odbcad32 is a GUI tool that comes with MS-Windows, lets you configure/test odbc data sources , thereby using the Db2 CLI driver (useful with ODBC.net data provider).   If you have one working machine, and another failing machine, you should determine the differences for the relevant components (.net, db2, certificates/encyption libraries, networks) and eliminate each one. This seems to be a matter of configuration not programming.